# MongoDb aggregate is reading same value multiple times

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this mongodb aggregate that is working and i am getting data in excel file. But in excel file i am seeing duplicate records even though it appears in the system for only one time. I am trying to understand why it is reading a value multiple times even though the filter value is occuring only once and not repeating itself. And how can i fix this issue? I know i need to make use of `$group` but i am having issue with its syntax so you help will be mich appreciated. Here is my aggregate

```
db.ParcelStatus.aggregate[
  { '$match': { createdAt: [Object], statusRepositoryId: [Object] } },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      from: 'Parcel',
      localField: 'parcelId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'parcel'
    }
  },
  { '$unwind': { path: '$parcel' } },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      from: 'ParcelStatus',
      localField: 'parcel._id',
      foreignField: 'parcelId',
      as: 'parcelStatuses'
    }
  },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      from: 'FinancialLedger',
      localField: 'parcel._id',
      foreignField: 'parcelId',
      as: 'financials'
    }
  },
  {
    '$unwind': { path: '$financials', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
  },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      from: 'CustomerData',
      localField: 'parcel.customerDataId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'customerData'
    }
  },
  { '$unwind': '$customerData' },
  { '$match': { 'customerData.cityId': [Object] } },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      from: 'Customer',
      localField: 'customerData.customerId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'customerData.customer'
    }
  },
  { '$unwind': '$customerData.customer' }
]
```

The issue is occuring because of `statusRepositoryId` in match filter as that id is the one i want to get grouped

here is a duplicate record in excel file

[image]

Sample JSON structre for ParcelStatus

```
[
  {
    "id": "string",
    "parcelId": "string",
    "vendorId": "string",
    "createdAt": "2020-07-17T07:23:17.630Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-07-17T07:23:17.630Z",
    "statusRepositoryId": "string"
  }
]
```

Sample JSON structure for financialLedger

```
[
  {
    "vendorId": "string",
    "parcelId": "string",
    "mutatedParcel": {},
    "id": "string",
    "createdAt": "2020-07-17T07:23:15.906Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-07-17T07:23:15.906Z"
  }
]
```

Sample Parcel JSON

```
{
  "id": "RWP597972414215",
  "currentStatusId": "5dd7fa20dcfa9600152cc2d8",
  "zoneAreaId": "ZONE_NOT_DEFINED",
  "vendorId": "5de137b8f0230b00128f9ae4",
  "createdAt": "2020-07-16T08:23:30.028Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-07-16T08:54:12.441Z",
  "pickupLocationId": "PL-831075",
  "description": "asdasdf",
  "customerDataId": "5f100e816811b9a11c3d5487",
  "previousStatusId": "5ee134230138634c27a6e1da",
  "loadsheetId": "LS-398866",
}
```

Sample Data JSON

```
{
    _id: 5efd93b80674f64f609f054d,
    parcelId: 'LHE044832446160',
    vendorId: 5e074ad0b0daa00012a4ebd0,
    createdAt: 2020-07-02T07:58:48.859Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-07-02T07:58:48.859Z,
    statusRepositoryId: 5dd7fa20dcfa9600152cc2e2,
    parcel: {
      _id: 'LHE044832446160',
      pickupLocationId: 'PL-379331',
      customerDataId: 5ef32b5f2141d84348b74770,
      currentStatusId: 5dd7fa20dcfa9600152cc2e2,
      previousStatusId: 5dd7fa20dcfa9600152cc2e3,
      loadsheetId: 'LS-834583',
      vendorId: '5e074ad0b0daa00012a4ebd0'
    },
    parcelStatuses: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ],
    financials: {
      _id: 5ef9b9989623f92d6c88b6c1,
      vendorId: 5e074ad0b0daa00012a4ebd0,
      parcelId: 'LHE044832446160',
      mutatedParcel: [Object],
      createdAt: 2020-06-29T09:51:20.303Z,
      updatedAt: 2020-06-29T09:51:20.303Z
    },
    customerData: {
      _id: 5ef32b5f2141d84348b74770,
      firstName: 'Ali Murtaza Hussain',
      email: 'test@test.com',
      lastName: 'Ali Murtaza Hussain',
      vendorId: 5e074ad0b0daa00012a4ebd0,
      createdAt: 2020-06-24T10:30:55.618Z,
      updatedAt: 2020-06-29T09:51:37.736Z,
      customerId: 5ef32b5f2141d84348b7476f,
      customer: [Object]
    }
  },
```

I have changed Ids and removed some other confidential data

Comment: When you use unwind it will create multiple copies of the document if there is more than one element in the array.  If you don't unwind, does it still return dupicates?

Comment: I never tried without unwind because unwind is necessary to turn lookup records from array to objects. So unwind is necessary and I am sure the issue is not because of unwind

Comment: Can you share please a sample data where you get duplicated result?

Comment: @Valijon updated the question with a snap of duplicate data.

Comment: the duplicate values are parcel ids

Comment: Share your data as JSON please, so we can perform your aggregation and fix the duplication error.

Comment: As mentioned the duplicates occurs due to the `$unwinds` it'll be easier to help you achieve the result you want if you give us data sample to work with a it's hard for me to guess how `customerData` or `financials` (which i think is the culprit) looks like.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert i want to share the JSON with you guys but the issue is that the response is just too much big from backend and the repitition is occuring at different places in JSON so if i even apply a limit of 10 it does not give me response that contains duplicate data. I am not sure how i can share the sample JSON with you guys

Comment: But it would be really helpful if you can tell me how i can use $group in my aggregate because i am trying to use distinct to get only one object and not duplicates. I remember distinct from SQL but not sure about how it can be used in mongo aggregate

Comment: I have just edited the question again with as much information as i am able to provide @TomSlabbaert please look into this now

Comment: I also requied the customer data, and the sample data should actually be creating a "dup" result. the main reason why I need this data as I can't guess if a lookup will result in 1 matching document (for example i'm assuming the first lookup will always be exactly 1 match) or more. the lookup that actually results in more than 1 match is the one causing duplicates most likely.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert check now. I have shared the specific parcelId that is getting duplicated becuase in its parcelStatus array the particular statusRepositoryId occurs more than 3 times. So i guess i need to make use of $group

Comment: You sample data is not complete, since you didn't post real data for `ParcelStatus`, `Parcel`, `CustomerData` and `Customer`. Please, share your data [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nedDPZNcwj1) where we get duplicated values( and share the link in your post) or we are forced to close your post since it's not reproducible